# Solving for variable in trig function

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I am having trouble solving for a in the following trig function and am looking for some help.

$$-\frac{1}{2}=\sin (6\times 2.90-6.28\times 2+a)$$

So what is $a$ equal to?

Comment: quick question off the bat: Degrees or Radians?

Comment: @imranfat radians.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

> in degrees

If $$\sin (X)=\sin (b ) $$ then

$$X=b+360k$$ or
$$X=180-b+360k$$

$$-\frac {1}{2}=\sin (-30)=\sin (a+4.84)$$

Comment: so then how do I solve my problem? I am a little confused

Comment: @Antoine Mathys so then can I drop the sin and just do 6*2.90-6.28*2+a=-pi/6?

Comment: i tried -5.36rad but this was incorrect

Comment: @user104 Are you okay now.

Comment: So a=-1.17??????

Comment: @jh123 $a\approx -34. 84$ degree or $a=145.14 $ deg.

Comment: How do you convert that to radians?

Comment: @jh123 Multiply by Pi=3.1415.. and divide by 180.

Comment: So then 2.53rad?

Answer (score 1):

Trigonometric functions like $\sin$ and $\cos$ are *periodic* with a period of $2\pi$. It is often a good idea then to restrict your attention to a single period of the function (say from $0$ to $2\pi$), solve your problem with that restriction in force and then worry about the solutions that are outside that range.

The first thing to do is to define a new variable to hide all the mess[1]:

$$
         \theta = 6\times 2.90 − 6.28\times 2 + a
$$

in terms of which your original equation becomes

$$
        \sin(\theta) = -\frac{1}{2}
$$

So ask yourself: what is the angle (or angles) whose $\sin$ is $-\frac{1}{2}$ in the given range? You probably know that $\sin(30^{\circ}) = \frac{1}{2}$ and $30^{\circ} = \frac{\pi}{6}$ radians. But you want the sine to be $-\frac{1}{2}$, so you have to keep going around the circle to find such a place. Restricting ourselves to our chosen range, there are actually two such angles. Can you see what they are?

Now you know there are two solutions for $\theta$ in the range $0$ to $2\pi$. Any other solution outside this range (and there are infinitely many) differs from one of these by an integral multiple of the period: $2\pi k, k= \pm 1, \pm 2, \dots$.

Finally, you can calculate $a$ by plugging in any of the values of $\theta$ thus obtained into its defining equation and solving for $a$.

Footnote:
[1] The "mess" can be simplified a bit, assuming you have not made a mistake in transcribing the equation, but I'm leaving it as is.

Comment: so $\frac {7pi}{6} = 6\times 2.90 − 6.28\times 2 + a$ then solve for a? So a=-1.17?

Comment: That's one solution (btw I did not check your arithmetic) - can you find another solution in the range $[0, 2\pi]$? After that it should be easy to state all of the solutions: two infinite families, one starting from the first solution and adding or subtracting an integer multiple of $2\pi$ and similarly for the second solution.

Answer (score 0):

So, define a number as $b:= 6×2.90−6.28×2$, then

first series is(where $k \in Z$):
$-\frac{1}{2}= sin(-\frac{\pi}{6} + 2\pi k) = sin(s^1_k)$

second series is(where $l \in Z$):
$-\frac{1}{2}= sin(-\frac{5\pi}{6} + 2\pi l) = sin(s^2_l)$

and total answer is:
$a = s^1_k -b$ and $a = s^2_l -b$